# Read 2D array from file with dimensions given in the first line

Tags: c, arrays, linux, multidimensional-array

I wrote a code to read 2D array of integers from file with dimensions given in the first line . while running it it gives me the following error :

*** Error in `./shell': double free or corruption (out): 0x000000000144a0c0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc , char* argv[])
{
FILE * fp;
char * line = NULL;
char * token ;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
int i;
int j ;
int flag = 0 ;
int row = 0 ;
int **matr ;
char cwd[1024];

getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) ;
char *matrix = malloc(strlen(cwd)+10);
// here but your file name

asprintf(&matrix,"%s%s",cwd,"/matrix");

fp = fopen(matrix, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
{

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        token = strtok (line," ");
        i = atoi(token);
        token = strtok (NULL, " ");
        if (token != NULL)
        {
            j = atoi(token);

        }
        printf("%d   %d\n",i,j);
        flag =1 ;
        matr = (int**)malloc(i*sizeof(int*));
        int e ;
        for(e=0; e<=i; e++)
        {
            matr[e] = (int*)malloc(j*sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    else if(row <i)
    {
        int col = 0 ;
        token = strtok (line,"\t");
        while (token != NULL && col<j)
        {
            matr[row][col] = atoi(token);
            printf("%d ",matr[row][col]);
            col++ ;
            token = strtok (NULL,"\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
        row++ ;
    }

  }

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

any solution ?

Comment: You don't actually `free` any of allocated memory . First start with freeing them .

Comment: I tried to free them but still the same problem !!

Comment: There is no 2D array. There are multiple errors. Review pointers, remove unnecessary casts and enable compiler warnings.

Comment: the question is about a runtime problem, however, the posted code is missing several #include statements (are we to guess which header files you included?)  and contains several other syntax problems.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: Please indent the code consistently.  For several reasons, never use tabs for indenting and use 4 spaces for each indent level.  suggest indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'  It also helps the readability of the code to separate code blocks (if, else, for, while, do...while, etc) with a blank line

Comment: regarding this line: `ssize_t read;`:  `read()` is a well known C library function prototyped in the unistd.h header file.   Using the name `read` for a variable name leads to confusion.  Please use unique variable names that are no the same as keywords in the language nor the names of C library macros, #defines, structs, nor functions

Comment: when calling the system function `malloc()`  <or calloc() or realloc()> always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in C, the returned value from `malloc()` and family of functions is a `void*`, so can be assigned to any other pointer.  1) this means the cast is not needed 2) the case just clutters the code and can lead to mis-understandings and other problems when debugging and/or performing maintenace

Comment: the system function: `strtok()` can fail, so do not use the returned value for anything until after checking (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0):

the posted code has a unrecoverable memory leak.

the pointer `matrix` is set to point to some allocated memory by a call to the malloc() function,

Then that pointer is overlayed by the call to asprintf() suggest either using sprintf() or replace the call to `malloc()` with `char *matrix = NULL;`